# Hoist dependencies of a file package in package.json

Tags: npm, node-modules, npm-install

Is there a way to hoist the dependencies of a file: specifier package using npm?

For example, I have the following package.json

```
{
    "dependencies": {
         "utils": "file:../utils"
    }
}
```

Doing npm install will result in the following node_modules

```
node_modules 
     utils (symlink)
        node_modules
            utils dependencies
```

I need a way to flat util's dependencies in the top-level node_modules

```
node_modules 
     utils (symlink)
     utils dependencies
```